# Convert Hexadecimal VARCHAR to binary VARCHAR

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a firebird database table with a column of type VARCHAR consisting of a hexadecimal number:

**MyColumn**
2020FF
731DD1
...

I want to select all rows of the table where the column converted from hexadecimal to binary contains the value 1 at the 7th bit (or 8th or 9th or any other) with one single SQL statement.

Example:

2020ff -> 001000000010000011111111 -> FALSE
731DD1 -> 011100110001110111010001 -> TRUE

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE SUBSTRING(hexToBinary(MyColumn),7,7)=1
```

Comment: There is no standard functionality in Firebird that would enable you to do this, you would need to write your own UDF; or find an existing UDF that does this.

Answer (score 2):

If the number in varchar column is small enough that it fits into 64bit integer you could cast it to `bigint` and then use [bin_and()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-bin_and.html) builtin function to check the state of the bit(s). Ie to check 7th bit:

```
SELECT MyColumn FROM myTable WHERE bin_and(cast('0x' || MyColumn as bigint), 64) <> 0;
```